# Python: Extracting value from list as a float rather than a list

Tags: python-3.x

First my apologies - I have just taught myself python over the last couple of weeks and this is definitely a rookie error - which I cannot for the life of me figure out

I have an unsorted list of floats (tileAverages) from which I wish to find the value closest to a separate float value (sourcePixel).

My code to do this is simplistic, but my problem is that whatever I do the value from tileAverages is returned as a list containing a single float - which then upsets abs or anything else I try to do with it. Casting makes no difference.

```
for loop in range(len(tileAverages)):
    tmpAvg=tileAverages[loop]  # tmpAvg is now a list, not the single float I dream off :)

    if abs(sourcePixel-tmpAvg) < temp:
        temp=abs(sourcePixel-tmpAvg)
        bestValue=tmpAvg
```

This is not elegant - but does bring back the right element - just enclosed in lovely square brackets of listness.

```
tmpAvg: [140.0403911564626]<class 'list'>
```

The error is:

```
if abs(sourcePixel-tmpAvg) < temp:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: what does `tileAverages` look like? is it a list of floats or a list of list of floats? Your code suggests the former but your error suggests the latter.

Comment: apologies for the delay.  printing out tileAverages gives me this: tileAverages: [[140.0403911564626], [150.88222789115648], [163.531037414966], [173.79464285714286], [181.09481292517006], [188.86479591836735], [200.57397959183675], [214.37925170068027], [228.1845238095238], [140.0403911564626], [150.88222789115648], [163.531037414966], [173.79464285714286], [181.09481292517006], [188.86479591836735], [200.57397959183675], [214.37925170068027], [228.1845238095238], [140.0403911564626], [150.88222789115648], [163.531037414966], [173.79464285714286],  ...

Comment: Try switching `tmpAvg=tileAverages[loop]` to `tmpAvg=tileAverages[loop][0]`.

Comment: Thanks JonSG - that worked and is something I never would have guessed :)

Comment: Your `tileAverages` is actually a "list of lists" with the sub-lists being just a list containing a single item. tacking the `[0]` on the end of `tmpAvg=tileAverages[loop]` just says "get that one item at index 0 from the list returned by `tileAverages[loop]`"

Comment: Thanks - it looks like I have a fair amount to learn about python - I haven't coded for about 40 years and some areas are a little different from C :)